# Printing numbers in the same line

Tags: python

As part of a set of exercises on loops, I am supposed to write a program that reads two integers X and Y. As the output, the program prints all integers from 1 to Y, organized in such a way that X numbers appear on each line.

So I'm supposed to use `while` or `for` somewhere. What I have so far is:

**Code**:

```
n_per_line = int(input('Numbers per line: '))
upperbound = int(input('Upper bound: '))

i = 1
n = 1

while i <= upperbound:
    while n <= n_per_line:
        print(i, end=' ')
        n += 1
        i += 1
```

However, this only prints out one line of output. For example,

```
Numbers per line: 3
Upper bound: 4

gives 1 2 3 in a single line. And

Numbers per line: 2
Upper bound: 4

gives 1 2 in a single line.
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: Please type your code as text in the question rather than showing a graphic of it. Copy-and-paste from your text editor into your question, highlight the code, then click the `{}` button so it will be formatted as text.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put a print for a new line

```
while con1:
    while con2:
        ...
        print(...,end=" ") #this print will put everything in the line
        ...
    print() #make a new line, so any following print use it
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
for i in range(1,b+1):
    print(i,end=' ')
    if i%a==0:print()
```